# How do I get user data from Express route through Ajax get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, get

I want to get data into a clientside js file to build charts dynamically depending on the user who is logged in.

I have a GET route that responds with the user data in a JSON Object when a user is logged in. I can use this JSON object in my EJS files so it is being sent through the route. But I want to use the same data in a client-side JavaScript file so I have an Ajax method that uses the same route. It is connecting to the route but I am not importing the json object.

```
routes.js 

    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        let respondent_id = req.user.user_respondent_id;
        getData(respondent_id, function (score) {
            //the user object can be rendered in the ejs files 
            res.status(200).render('profile.ejs',{user: req.user, score})
        });
    });
```

I want to use that same json object in client-side js file

```
public/javascripts/graph.js

var getData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/profile',

            console.log(data.score.cat1Total.score); //undefined on console.
            //data undefined 
            myChart.chartArray.push(data.score.cat1Total.score);

            // These are the variables I want to take from JSON object from /profile - they are working, as on EJS file they display. 
            // [score.cat1Total.score, score.cat2Total.score,
            //     score.cat3Total.score, score.cat4Total.score, 
            //     score.cat5Total.score, score.cat6Total.score,
            //     score.cat7Total.score, score.cat8Total.score]

            // re-render the chart
            myChart.update();
        }
    });
};

// get user data
getData();
```

when I also try to print just the data it prints the profile.ejs file out